# How to AutoMap Elasticsearch properties using NEST object initializer syntax

Tags: elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

Is there a way to use NEST's `AutoMap` functionality with the Object Initializer Syntax?

According to the tutorial [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net-example/tree/6.x-netcore), the Object Initializer Syntax is "fully supported throughout the client." So, using an example from the tutorial, how would I perform this mapping using the Object Initializer Syntax?

```
.Nested<PackageDependency>(nn => nn
    .Name(pv => pv.Dependencies.First())
    .AutoMap()
)
```

I've tried it like this:

```
new NestedProperty
{
    Name = new PropertyName(nameof(PackageVersion.Dependencies))
}
```

But I can't find a property on the `NestedProperty` object that would corespond to `AutoMap`. The same goes for `TextProperty`, etc.

If it's not possible, I'll just use the Fluent API Syntax - no problem. But I want to make sure I'm not missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've managed to find a method, `AutoMap()`, that has no directly corresponding counterpart in the Object Initializer syntax :) Because there is no generic type parameter to represent the CLR type available, it can't be modelled the same way.

You can however achieve the same effect with using the components that `AutoMap` uses

```cs
var nestedProperty = new NestedProperty
{
    Name = Nest.Infer.Property<PackageVersion>(pv => pv.Dependencies.First()),
    Properties = new Properties<PackageDependency>(
        new PropertyWalker(typeof(PackageDependency), null).GetProperties())
};
```

which will yield the following JSON assigned the field name resolved from `Nest.Infer.Property<PackageVersion>(pv => pv.Dependencies.First())` (by default will be `dependencies`)

```
{
  "type": "nested",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    },
    "version": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    },
    "framework": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you need to override any properties that will be automapped this way, you can either do so on the `IProperties` returned from `.GetProperties()` method call or using the indexer on `Properties<T>`, which is `Properties<PackageDependency>` in this example.

Comment: Ah... perfect. Thanks so much - that's exactly what I was looking for!